# HDRI image in scene world background is too large to see when rotating

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, scene, hdri

My HDRI image in scene world background is too large to see when rotating. So I don't see where the sun is from the picture when I rotate the HDRI. is there a solution for that.

Comment: too large? the whole image should be displayed, could you please tell a bit more?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49042/how-do-i-scale-down-zoom-out-an-environment-texture/