# How to edit photos in background for rendering

Tags: rendering, image, shader-nodes

This question is mainly about shrinking the image on the background, but does anyone know how to edit the textures of world?

I'm trying to have this one guys face as the background to my planetary diagram, but the face is too large and it would be nice to be able to do other things to it as well

[image]

This is my current node setup for world

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49042/how-do-i-scale-down-zoom-out-an-environment-texture ?