Lining up scene ground with z = 0
I'm trying to use an HDRi image I found on the web as the background for an animation.
The brick circle in the picture below is flat with the X-Y plane, and at z = -1.8 meters.  In the image, it appears much smaller and angled down into the grass.
Is there a way to adjust the apparent height of the world background so that the ground is at some predefined altitude?
Failing that, if I grab my cell phone and go take some pictures, how do I generate an HDMi image that'll work here?  Or is there some technique to use other than setting the world background?


Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49046/19307

Don't ask two questions in one, please.

There is no way to alter the apparent altitude of a 360 degree image after it was taken, at least not without some fakery like stretching the ground and squashing the sky. The simplest way to do the fakery in Blender is with a Mapping node operating on the default Generated Texture Coordinate for the environment, adjusting the Z Location transform as desired.


So -- I just can't get there from here.  Am I correct that I either need a 360-degree picture that's taken from my camera height above ground, or I need to find a flat panorama that I can displace up or down?

I don’t know what you mean by the second statement, but the first one is correct.

1). You could use image as planes to use at certain angles from the camera view (I assume you've tried translating the coordinates in the world texture nodes and it still looks 'fish eye').
2). You could create a huge floor/horizon plane. BlenderGuru has a free node group that helps with seamless textures which would be ideal for the grass in your scene.
BlenderGuru link

Try Fspy and do a short Tutorial on it!
Here you can get the Software: https://fspy.io/
For Blender users, there is an official fSpy importer add-on that sets the parameters of the Blender camera and optionally sets the camera background image.
Blender-Addon: https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender#getting-started
Here is the Tutorial for the Software Fspy:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=704NgSWO5fk&ab_channel=SanningArkitekter
HDRI Images like the name said, needs High Dynamic Range. So, I guess your cellphone is not sophisticated enough, that it can do that. You require a technique called HDR bracketing. You need at least 3 stages for an HDR and (3 Images)
It is called Multi-exposure HDR capture.
You can do that with a camera lets say:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_4000D
Short Introduction:
https://pixls.us/articles/hdr-photography-with-free-software-luminancehdr/
But if you do not want to do your own HDR-Images you can grab some from for example from:
https://hdri-haven.com/

This doesn’t seem to answer the question…?
